# Loading html from a different domain using easyXDM

Tags: javascript, jquery, easyxdm

I am trying to load html from a different site using easyXDM, but it does not work for me when I try to do it through HTTP GET.

Does anyone know what is the cause for the problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    var rpc = new easyXDM.Rpc({
        remote: "http://anything.com"
    },
    {
        remote: {
            request: {}
        }
    });

    rpc.request({
        url: "/default.aspx",
        method: "GET"
    }, function (response) {
        alert(response);
    });


</script>
```

​

Thanks.

Comment: are you setting CORS support correctly? jQuery and easyXDM are two different libraries.

Comment: Did you end up finding any solution?